# Throw away sound effects in Javascript using HTML5 audio?

Tags: javascript, audio, html

I'm building a simple game using a canvas tag and want to add some sound effects to it.
If I use the following code to play the SFX...

```
function playSfx( sound ) {
 var snd = new Audio("file.mp3");
 snd.play();
}
```

Is the garbage collection / memory management clever enough to play the sound and then dispose of the Audio object? Or will I have to keep track of the object and destroy it when it has finished playing?

Comment: I'd be more worried about tepid audio support: Safari+Chrome can play MP3, Firefox you need Ogg-Vorbis or Wav, Opera you need Wav, and IE you have to fall back on a flash player.

Comment: I'm not worried about coding for IE6,7 and 8 since they dont support most of the work I have done (it's a personal project so I don't have to worry about browser usage). Is there no "one format" for the browsers which support HTML5? WebM works in all but Safari right?